Complicated filter excel formula
I am trying to create a filter that can filter one column for one word and a different column with a different word so that it will only pull up Column A word that also matches with Column B's word. I"m trying to create a card sorter that does not need for people to do into the database part and do the top column filter (probably easier but not for those not excel savy) but if they can just select the 2 or 3 things they want to search by and not have to go in the database that would be better. I used this formula for one column:
=FILTER(Sheet2!A7:K61,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B3,Sheet2!D7:D61))) 

I tried
=FILTER(Sheet2!A7:K61,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,C2,Sheet2!D7:E61))) 

and got #VALUE!
Is what I'm trying to do even possible or am I just having a bad coding day and can't think it through well enough to get what I want? Thanks so much!


consider this screenshot

The formula in cell G7 is
=FILTER($B$3:$D$18,($C$3:$C$18=$G$4)*($D$3:$D$18=$G$5))

To combine multiple criteria in a Filter() function, you have to multiply them.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
